# Size/length limitations of bash scripts

Tags: bash

I am wondering if there is any size, length or even run-time limitations with bash scripts. I am installing php-hiphop on debian squeeze(I know it's not ubuntu but I presumed there were some bash experts hanging around here) on a test server, and there is quite a lot of extra libraries and configuring to do before even attempting to compile hiphop so I plan to make a bash script so that updating other servers will be quicker. I'm pretty new to linux systems, this is actually my first time properly using one, and I have no idea how much or how little bash files can do.

As an example, I have to update gcc to 4.6 which at the `make` command is taking 5+ hours, and was wondering even after that long will the bash script be able to continue? I have also noticed one can use multiple bash scripts and use `wait` to wait for a command to finish then execute another script, would this be a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Size limit? lol If you have a bash file that's over a megabyte in size, then you'd probably be better off using a real programming language. Though, a bash script could be way over 100 megabytes in size if you really want to know.  :)

Comment: Ha I should have phrased that better. I suppose size is the wrong word here, I mean "amount of commands" or something like that.

Comment: If the command you want will work in the terminal, then it will work in a bash script. As for the number of commands- I suppose that is only limited by your hardware.

Comment: Thanks Sepero, really helps. I'll let you know how my 4.76GB bash file went when I finish running it :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never run into limitations on size or time, and as long as your script isn't hampering the system in some way-there is no limitation.

I have a script that backs up all my servers to a network location, it runs for 19 hours. as far as sizes? scripts are only text files, how big could it get? bash scripting a great because of its few limitations, enjoy!

hope this answers your question!

thanks
jm

Comment: Thanks that really helps. I don't mean size as in memory, although I should have phrased it better, I kind of meant it as number of commands, as in "the size of what it does". I swear it makes sense in my head.

Comment: oh, well that shouldn't matter either, my back up script is about 60 commands. 1 create backup, 2 move backup, 3, verify.. then repeat for 20 servers. good luck scripting!

Comment: I seem to have an issue where bash's character buffer is only so large... Apparently my 12,000-line is too big - bash gives a syntax error about an unexpected newline.

Comment: @iAdjunct: take a look at [this answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662506/bash-script-size-limitation/38662878) and the Unix/Linux answer it links to.